# Different appearence of liqueur after aging

Tags: aging, color, liquor, nuts

Last year I have made walnuts liqueur, or nocino in Italian.

From the single batch I have obtained 2 liters of liqueur, which I have bottled in dark beer bottles and left to age in the same, dark room.

Now I have noticed that while the liquor in one bottle has achieved the dark brown color typical of the liqueur, in another bottle the liquor is greenish and opaque.

What can have happened?

Comment: Does it smell bad?

Comment: A picture or two would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, contamination has turned your second bottle greenish.